# I can't open Unity tweak tool

Tags: unity, command-line, launcher, unity-tweak-tool

I can't seem to open the [Unity][1] tweak tool, either from the launcher or dash or terminal. In the terminal, I got these errors:
    t***@t***-desktop:~$ unity-tweak-tool

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "/usr/bin/unity-tweak-tool", line 72, in <module>

 UnityTweakTool.Application()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UnityTweakTool/__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
 executable_name=cmd_old.split('\x00')[1]
```

IndexError: list index out of range

How can I fix this problem?

**Update**
got another error from launching from terminal:

```
WARNING **: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/unity-tweak-tool", line 72, in <module>
UnityTweakTool.Application()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UnityTweakTool/__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
executable_name=cmd_old.split('\x00')[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: error like that, i usually do this: `sudo apt-get purge unity-tweak-tool && sudo apt-get autoremove` and then install it again: `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`

Comment: This was a [reported bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-tweak-tool/+bug/1258536). The fix has been released. Follow the method suggested by @blade19899

Comment: sorry, but that's not working, i've already tried it and tried once again now, i'm using 14.4 trusty, and do i need to add a seperate PPA to get the latest version?

Comment: What version of the unity tweak tool do you have installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run bleachbit from terminal as SUDO and clear system cache.  I had the same problem and that resolved it.

Comment: Perhaps they need to install bleachbit first?

Comment: To improve this answer, you could add instructions of which commands are needed to install and then run bleachbit, perhaps also a screenshot of which option to select, etc.

Comment: no no no, i got bleachbit installed long before, what i did is that i reinstalled unity-tweak-tool and cleared system cache then restarted the system. sometime it works, sometime it wont works.

Comment: Clearly it worked....got the green check mark...THANK YOU! THANK YOU! THANK YOU!...WHO IS YOUR DADDY NOW BIIIOTCH?

Comment: Yes Seth, that is correct, he/she needed to install bleachbit first.  I was in such a rush to help out I omitted that.